# angular ngrx store error Cannot read property 'schedule' of undefined

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I tried to implement ngrx/Store with Angular but I am always getting the following error in console, and no content is showed:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'schedule' of undefined
>       at ObserveOnSubscriber.scheduleMessage"

By the way I am using:

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Angular: 5.2.11

Since I am new to ngrx/Store I am trying to implement the following example:
https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngrx-guide

Even I tried with other examples but I am getting always the same above mentioned error.

Comment: Please paste some basic codes on how your store is setup. You could also look at the example app on the repo.

Comment: Please provide details about your app.Module, component which subscribe, actions, reduces, state (and effects? )

Comment: Thanks for the replies. In fact I tried to implement this example since I am beginner to ngrx/store: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngrx-guide

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was facing same issue while integrating the `ngRx/Store` in a new application. When I checked the `npm install` log, I noticed this:

> npm WARN **@ngrx/store@6.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0** but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

This lead me to believe that `@ngRx/Store v6.x` requires `Angular v6`. After uninstalling the `@ngRx/Store v6` and downgrading to `ngRx/Store` **`v5.2.0`**, everything worked like a charm.

Solution in steps:

1. `npm uninstall @ngrx/store`
2. `npm install @ngrx/store@5`
3. re-compile app

Added some more line due to edits restriction

Comment: @Sayed Ali Taqi: Thanks Syed for the answer, but please after uninstalling I am getting this error when trying to install the version 5.2.0:                                                                                                  
`npm i @ngrx/store 5.2.0
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 5.2.0@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jocopernicus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-07T21_47_04_454Z-debug.log`

Comment: But downgrading to the version 4.1.1 solved the problem, I also tried with another project after upgrading angular version to 6 then it worked also.  So Thanks a lot @Syed Ali Taqi for your help

Comment: @TigrisLaesus: pleasure, please mark the answer as accepted so that it may be helpful if anybody else faces same problem.

Comment: @Sayed Ali Taqi: sorry for the delay since I am new to stackoverflow.. and thanks again for the answer that was very helpful to me

Comment: Changing step 2 to: "npm install @ngrx/store@5.2.0" works for me. Thanks

Comment: Downgrading to store@5 would require a downgrade of angular/core to 5.0 and rxjs to 5.5 also, something I definitely dont want. Is there another solution ?

Comment: @Nekudotayim: what version of Angular do you currently have?

Comment: @SyedAliTaqi Thank you, your solution worked like a charm for me.